# PageView is consuming all gestures with embedded webview in flutter

Tags: flutter, events, webview, gesture

I have an embedded web view that is nested alongside a pageview builder which controls my three js animations by sending javascript to the embedded web view.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/data/bloc/artifacts.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/domain/models/artifact_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/ui/discover/widgets/animatedCardTutorial.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/ui/discover/widgets/focusPointList.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/ui/discover/widgets/questionMarkButton.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/ui/discover/widgets/threeJSViewer.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/ui/widgets/assetOrCachedNetworkImage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/ui/widgets/circularBackButton.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/ui/widgets/simpleVideo.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/ui/widgets/videoPlayerControllers.dart';

double deviceHeight = 0.0;
double deviceWidth = 0.0;

class ArtifactView extends StatefulWidget {
  ArtifactView({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ArtifactView> createState() => _ArtifactViewState();
}

class _ArtifactViewState extends State<ArtifactView> {
  bool _fullscreen = false;
  AbstractVideoPlayerController? videoPlayerController;

  Timer? _restoreUiTimer;

  int? startUpCount;
  bool shouldShowTutorial = false;

  void startFullScreen() {
    if (!_fullscreen) {
      setState(() {
        _fullscreen = true;
        _restoreUiTimer?.cancel();
        _restoreUiTimer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1500), endFullScreen);
      });
    }
  }

  void endFullScreen() {
    setState(() {
      _fullscreen = false;
    });
  }

  void hideTutorial() {
    setState(() {
      shouldShowTutorial = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(DeviceOrientation.values);
    videoPlayerController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // hide status bar when displaying fullscreen artifact.  (otherwise show status bar)
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: _fullscreen ? [] : SystemUiOverlay.values);

    return BlocConsumer<ArtifactsBloc, ArtifactsState>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      builder: (context, state) {
        Artifact artifact = state.hasArtifact ? state.currentArtifact : Artifact.empty;

        //List<FocusPoint> focusPoints = state.hasArtifact ? state.focusPoints : [];
        //String modelFilePath = state.modelPath;
        //bool modelIsAsset = isAssetUrl(modelFilePath);

        if (videoPlayerController == null && artifact.uuid == 'ironman_artifact') {
          // EasterEgg  // TODO - have Kodi add the polka.mp3 file to our CDN and reference that below instead of userbob.com
          videoPlayerController = createVideoPlayerController('https://userbob.com/motb/polka.mp3', useChewie: true);
          videoPlayerController?.initialize();
          videoPlayerController?.play();
        }

        // FIXME - trying to always display background sized to device's dimensions so that the background
        // doesn't shift when switching to full-screen mode.  The code below will prevent the background from
        // shifting after the first time we've gone into full-screen mode.  However, the very first time
        // their will be a slight shift.
        //!FIXME - We should look into the overlfow widdget to let the scaffold know we intend to let this widget be larger than the screen.
        var windowSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        if (windowSize.height > deviceHeight) deviceHeight = windowSize.height;
        if (windowSize.width > deviceWidth) deviceWidth = windowSize.width;

        return Center(
          child: Container(
            height: deviceHeight,
            width: deviceWidth,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                if (videoPlayerController != null)
                  SimpleVideo(
                    placeholderImage: 'asset://images/discover/washingtonrevelations.webp',
                    videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController!,
                  ),
                if (artifact.backgroundUrl.isNotEmpty)
                  Container(
                    height: deviceHeight,
                    width: deviceWidth,
                    child: AssetOrCachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: artifact.backgroundUrl, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: RadialGradient(
                      radius: 0.9,
                      colors: [
                        Colors.transparent,
                        Colors.transparent,
                        Colors.black38,
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  height: deviceHeight,
                  width: deviceWidth,
                ),
                Listener(
                  onPointerDown: (PointerDownEvent e) {
                    startFullScreen();
                  },
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onPanEnd: ((details) {
                      print('ended');
                    }),
                    child: ThreeJSViewer(
                      modelFilePath: state.modelPath,
                      initScale: artifact.cameraZoom.toInt(),
                      autoRotateSpeed: 2,
                      state: state,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                    child: CircularBackButton(
                      outterPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 0, 0),
                      onTap: () {
                        AutoRouter.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                AnimatedPositioned(
                  bottom: 60 - (_fullscreen ? 250 : 0.0),
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: FocusPointList(
                      state: state,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

finally here is my WebView plus widget

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/data/bloc/artifact/artifacts_state.dart';
import 'package:internet_connection_checker/internet_connection_checker.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter_plus/webview_flutter_plus.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class ThreeJSViewer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? modelFilePath;
  final String? modelURLPath;
  final double? autoRotateSpeed;
  final int initScale;
  final ArtifactsState state;
  final bool? debug;

  final void Function(PointerMoveEvent)? onPointerMove;
  ThreeJSViewer({
    Key? key,
    this.modelFilePath,
    this.onPointerMove,
    this.modelURLPath,
    required this.initScale,
    this.autoRotateSpeed,
    required this.state,
    this.debug,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ThreeJSViewer> createState() => _ThreeJSViewerState();
}

class _ThreeJSViewerState extends State<ThreeJSViewer> {
  int progress = 0;

  WebViewPlusController? controller;
  bool isRendered = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == true) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              if (progress < 100 && isRendered == true)
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      value: progress.toDouble(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              WebViewPlus(
                initialCookies: [],
                gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
                zoomEnabled: false,
                gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
                  new Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                    () {
                      print('GestureRecognizer created');
                      return new EagerGestureRecognizer();
                    },
                  ),
                ].toSet(),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                javascriptChannels: ({
                  JavascriptChannel(
                    name: 'JavascriptChannel',
                    onMessageReceived: (message) {
                      if (message == "200") {
                        setState(() {
                          isRendered = true;
                        });
                      }
                      log(message.message);
                    },
                  )
                }),
                onProgress: (_progress) {
                  setState(() {
                    progress = _progress;
                  });
                },
                onWebViewCreated: (_controller) {
                  controller = _controller;
                  _controller.loadUrl("assets/renderer/index.html");
                },
                onPageFinished: (value) {
                  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
                    this.widget.state.controller = controller?.webViewController;
                    this.widget.state.controller!.runJavascript(
                          'init("${this.widget.modelFilePath ?? this.widget.modelURLPath}", ${this.widget.initScale},${this.widget.initScale},${this.widget.initScale}, ${this.widget.autoRotateSpeed ?? 2}, ${this.widget.debug ?? false})',
                        );
                  });
                },
                onPageStarted: (value) {
                  log(value);
                },
                onWebResourceError: (value) {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(
                      content: Text('Error loading model. Please make sure you have internet connection.'),
                    ),
                  );
                  log(value.description);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              child: DefaultTextStyle(
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                child: Text(
                  "no internet connection",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      future: InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection,
    );
  }
}
```

My WebView is able to accept all gesture events when I initially rotate or zoom the three js model, but when I swipe a card on the pageview builder it consumes whatever gesture event for the duration of the widget lifetime.

finally here are the pageview cards

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/data/bloc/artifact/artifacts_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/domain/models.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/ui/discover/views/focusPointView.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/ui/discover/widgets/focusPointCard.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:flutter_museum/app/data/bloc/artifacts.dart';

class FocusPointList extends StatefulWidget {
  final ArtifactsState state;

  const FocusPointList({Key? key, required this.state}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FocusPointList> createState() => _FocusPointListState();
}

class _FocusPointListState extends State<FocusPointList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _centeredFocusPointIndex = 0;
    ArtifactsState _state = this.widget.state;
    List<FocusPoint> focusPoints = _state.hasArtifact ? _state.focusPoints : [];

    List artifactFocusPointsList = focusPoints
        .map(
          (fp) => FocusPointCard(
            publisher: fp.publisher ?? '',
            subtitle: fp.subtitle ?? '',
            title: fp.title,
            imageUrl: fp.thumbnailImageUrl,
            externalLink: fp.externalLink,
            cardOnTap: () => _handleTapOnCard(context: context, focusPoint: fp),
          ),
        )
        .toList();

    return Container(
      height: 160,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: PageView.builder(
        itemCount: artifactFocusPointsList.length,
        controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.75),
        onPageChanged: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _centeredFocusPointIndex = index;
            FocusPoint afp = focusPoints[index];
            bool isPointsEmpty = afp.x + afp.y + afp.z != 0;

            if (index < focusPoints.length - 1 && isPointsEmpty) {
              _centeredFocusPointIndex = index;
              _state.controller?.runJavascript('tweenCamera(${afp.x}, ${afp.y}, ${afp.z}, 2000);');
            }
          });
        },
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return Transform.scale(
            scale: index == _centeredFocusPointIndex ? 1 : 0.9,
            child: artifactFocusPointsList[index],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleTapOnCard({required BuildContext context, required FocusPoint focusPoint}) {
    if (focusPoint.externalLink != null) {
      launch(focusPoint.externalLink!);
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => FocusPointView(
            title: focusPoint.title,
            subtitle: focusPoint.subtitle ?? '',
            publisher: focusPoint.publisher ?? '',
            imageUrl: focusPoint.detailImageUrl ?? '',
            description: focusPoint.description ?? '',
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```